# bindpopup not firing on markers for leafletjs

Tags: leaflet, marker

I am using leafletjs to show maps and place some markers on them. I have been stuck on a weird issue wherein for some markers the popup does not show up. On playing with it i found that when i take the dummy lat longs from google map it does fire but not for the lat longs that i have from my data. But in both cases i do have the markers attached to the map. So if there is a problem with lat longs how do i see them marked correctly on the map? 
popup fires when i have this as latlong:

```
lat: "1.478744"
long: "-0.295573"
```

and it wont fire for this:

```
lat: "51.483679748651"
long: "-0.29162660006234"
```

Here' s my code:

```
<html style='height: 100%; width: 100%;'>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="src/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/L.Control.Sidebar.css" />

<style>
    body {
        padding: 30px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    @font-face { font-family: Roboto-Medium; src: url('fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'); } 
    @font-face { font-family: Roboto-Regular; src: url('fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'); } 

    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    #sidebar {
        padding: 24px;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        float: right;            
        font-family: monospace;
    }

    hr { width:100%; height:1px; background: #fff }

    .popLabelTitle {
        color: #000000;                     
        font-family: Roboto-Regular;
        font-size: 20
    }

    .popLabelSubTitle {
        color: #505050;                     
        font-family: Roboto-Regular;
        font-size: 14
    }

    .popLabelBlurred {
        color: #505050;                     
        font-family: Roboto-Medium;
        font-size: 14
    }
    .radioTitle {
        color: #505050;                     
        font-family: Roboto-Regular;
        font-size: 14           
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>


    <div id="sidebar">
        <span style="font-family: Roboto-Regular;">Filter</span><br>            
        <input backgroundColor="red" type="radio" name="filter" value="schedule" > <label class="radioTitle" >Schedule</label> <br>            
        <input type="radio" name="filter" value="risk"> <label class="radioTitle" >Risk</label> <br>
        <input type="radio" name="filter" value="opm"> <label class="radioTitle" >OPM</label> <br>  
        <input  type="radio" name="filter" value="location"> <label class="radioTitle" >Location</label> <br>  
        <input  type="radio" name="filter" value="all" checked> <label class="radioTitle" >All</label> <br>  
    </div>    

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="src/L.Control.Sidebar.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {                
         $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
                //alert(this.value);
            });     

        });        

        var map;
        var poiData = [{
            "id" : "15555",
            "color": "blue",
            "address" : "5 Rue de l'Arcade, 11400 Castelnaudary, France",
            "description" : "",
            "lat" : "51.47344681882283",
            "lon" : "-0.3091066283535285",
            "name" : "Le Petit Gazouilli",
            "zoom_show" : "2"                
        },{
            "id" : "142065",
            "color": "green",
            "address" : "5 Rue de l'Arcade, 11400 Castelnaudary, France",
            "description" : "",
            "lat" : "51.483679748651",
            "lon" : "-0.29162660006234",
            "name" : "Le Petit ",
            "zoom_show" : "2"
        }];       


        window.onresize = function() {

            Ti.API.info('********** RESIZE FUNCTION IS CALLED1!!!!! window.innerHeight' + window.innerHeight + ' //// document.body.clientHeight = ' + document.body.clientHeight);
            // outputs window.innerheight =
            document.getElementById("map").style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
            // maybe change this to html/body tag to let it be a more generic fix.
            map.invalidateSize();
            // relevant to your leaflet map to trigger resizing / redrawing /filling.
        };

        var path = "",
            obj = "",
            center = "",
            bounds = "",
            minZoomLevel = "",
            maxZoomLevel = "";
        /*
        Ti.App.addEventListener("app:startWebview", function(e) {
            obj = JSON.parse(e.pois);
            center = JSON.parse(e.center);
            minZoomLevel = JSON.parse(e.minZoomLevel);
            maxZoomLevel = JSON.parse(e.maxZoomLevel);
            bounds = JSON.parse(e.bounds);
            createMap();

        });*/
            obj = poiData;
            center = [51.478744, -0.295573];                
            minZoomLevel = 16;
            maxZoomLevel = 18;
            //bounds = [[51.470103, -0.310407], [51.478376, -0.280567]];
            bounds = [[51.470103, -0.310407], [51.486674, -0.286572]]; //sw,ne

            createMap();

        function createMap() {
            //alert('2s');

            var points = obj;
            map = L.map('map', {
                //center : [51.47834563230677, -0.29832356080899747],
                //layers: [tileLayer['Gray'], groupA, groupB], 
                center : center,
                zoom : minZoomLevel,
                zoomControl : true                    
            });


            var tl = L.tileLayer('mapTiles/richmond/{z}_{x}_{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6IjZjNmRjNzk3ZmE2MTcwOTEwMGY0MzU3YjUzOWFmNWZhIn0.Y8bhBaUMqFiPrDRW9hieoQ', {
                minZoom : minZoomLevel,
                maxZoom : maxZoomLevel,
                bounds : bounds,
                //maxNativeZoom : 14,
                unloadInvisibleTiles : true,
                id : 'mapbox.streets'

            }).addTo(map);


            map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

    var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {            
        closeButton: false,
        position: 'right'
    });
    map.addControl(sidebar);
     sidebar.show();

    setTimeout(function () {
        sidebar.show();
    }, 500);
    tl.on("load",function() { 
        //alert("all visible tiles have been loaded");
});
            var poiLayer,
                indicatorMarker;



            function onClick(e) {
                alert('clicked a poi! ');
                //Ti.API.info("click " + JSON.stringify(e.target.options.item));
                // if (e && e.target && e.target.options && e.target.options.item) {
                // alert('clicked a poi!');
                // Ti.App.fireEvent("app:openPoi", {
                // poiItem : JSON.stringify(e.target.options.item)
                // });
                // }
            }

            var zoomFactor = 0.8;
            function addPois(zoom) {
                var poiArray = [];
                if (poiLayer) {
                    poiLayer.clearLayers();
                }

                for (var i = 0,j = points.length; i < j; i++) {
                    //alert('ss');
                    var item = points[i];
                    //   if (showPoi(item, zoom)) {

                    // var w = 50;
                    //var h = 60;

                    var w = 28;
                    var h = 42;

                    if (currentZoom === 16) {
                        w = w * zoomFactor;
                        h = h * zoomFactor;
                    }

                    /*
                     var icon = "",
                     iconHtml = "";

                     if (item.recommended) {
                     icon = "rec_tapped_poi";
                     }
                     if (item.favourited) {
                     icon = "fav_tapped_poi";
                     }

                     if (icon) {
                     iconHtml = '<img style="width:15px;height:15px;position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-7px;top:-6px" src="images/' + icon + '.png">';
                     }
                     */

                    var pinIcon = "";

                    if (item.color == "blue") {
                        pinIcon = "mapMarkerBlue";
                    }
                    if (item.color == "green") {
                        pinIcon = "mapMarkerGreen";
                    }
                    if (item.color == "purple") {
                        pinIcon = "mapMarkerPurple";
                    }
                    var myIcon = L.divIcon({                            
                        iconSize : [w, h],
                        iconAnchor : [(w / 2), h],
                        className : "testclass",
                        html : '<img style="width:' + w + 'px;height:' + h + 'px" src="images/poi_icons/' + pinIcon + '.png">'
                    });

                    poiArray.push(L.marker([item.lat, item.lon], {
                        icon : myIcon,
                        item : item,                                                    
                    }).addTo(map).bindPopup(L.popup({offset:(0,1)}).setContent("<div><label class='popLabelTitle' >12345678</label></div>" 
                        + "<div><label  class='popLabelSubTitle' >Last Inspected 1/1/11</label></div>" 
                        + "<hr /><div><label  class='popLabelBlurred' >Dashboard</label></div>")));                        

                };

                poiLayer = L.layerGroup(poiArray);

                poiLayer.addTo(map);
            }

            addPois(currentZoom);

            //var currentZoom = 12;
            var currentZoom = 16;
            map.on('zoomend', function(e) {

                var z = map.getZoom();

                if (currentZoom != z) {
                    currentZoom = z;

                   // addPois(z);
                }
            });

            Ti.App.addEventListener("app:addPoints", function(e) {

                if (e.points) {
                    Ti.API.info(e.points);
                    points = e.points;
                    addPois(currentZoom);
                }
            });                

        }


    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a sidebar on the right side of the map which was blocking the clicks on the marker near the sidebar area. Thanks

Comment: There's an edit button under your question.... You should use it. This isn't an answer.